# Detailsview doesn't show textboxes when there is no data

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, detailsview

I am using DetailsView only for Inserting data, for select, update and delete I use Gridview. So when there is no data in the table I don't see the textboxes to insert new data, how to fix this?. Any help is appreciated!

DetailsView code

```
 <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" DefaultMode="Insert" OnItemInserted= "Inserted" 
              AutoGenerateInsertButton="True" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Name, Software, License Number" AutoGenerateRows="true" 
              DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None">
              <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
              <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" />
              <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
              <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#E9ECF1" Font-Bold="True" />
              <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
              <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
              <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
              <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
          </asp:DetailsView>
</asp:Panel>


<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/Test.mdb"
         SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Softwares]"               
         InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO Softwares ([Name],[Softwares],[License Number],[Software Version],[Expiration Date],[Notes]) 
         VALUES ([WhichName],[WhichSoft],[WhichLice],[WhichSoftVer],[WhichExp],[WhichNotes])"           
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Softwares] SET [Software Version] = ?,
           [Expiration Date] = ?,[Notes] = ? WHERE [Name]=? AND [Softwares] = ? AND [License Number] = ? "                
            DeleteCommand = "DELETE FROM [Softwares] WHERE [Name]=? AND  [Softwares] = ? AND [License Number] = ?" >          

            <InsertParameters>
                   <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Softwares" Type="String" />
                     <asp:Parameter Name="License Number" Type="String" />
                      <asp:Parameter Name="Software Version" Type="String" />
                       <asp:Parameter Name="Expiration Date" Type="String" />
                       <asp:Parameter Name="Notes" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>

            <UpdateParameters>   
                    <asp:Parameter  Name="Software Version"  Type="String"/>
                    <asp:Parameter  Name="Expiration Date"  Type="String"/>
                    <asp:Parameter  Name="Notes"  Type="String"/>
                    <asp:Parameter  Name="Name" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter  Name="Softwares"  Type="String"/>
                    <asp:Parameter  Name="License Number"  Type="String"/>                                                               
                </UpdateParameters>

            <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter  Name="Name" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter  Name="Softwares"  Type="String"/>
                    <asp:Parameter  Name="License Number"  Type="String"/> 
                </DeleteParameters>                     
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Comment: Have you tried selecting the fields one by one instead of select * ? I also find it is better to use code behind on datagrids instead of the wizard.

Comment: I tried that, but didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good tutorial. You should be able to get everything you need by following this tutorial.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/custom-formatting/using-templatefields-in-the-detailsview-control-cs

Comment: I am looking for DetailsView, the tutorial is about Gridview.

Comment: I am a goof. Sorry, I was thinking grid.

Comment: I found the solution with this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.autogeneraterows.aspx?wwparam=1356036212)! Basically when AutoGenerateRows set to True then the fields are not stored, so I need to declare row fields explicitly and that solved the issue. Thanks for the help and I am marking it as answer since you pointed to templatefields but I am adding this link as well to the answer.